# Temporal Spatial Databases/Data Processing Frameworks

Tags: database, geolocation, time-series, geospatial, data-processing

I have a dataset of flights that contain multiple temporal position measurements, i.e.

- A timestamp of when the position measurement was taken
- A 3-dimensional vector containing the latitude, longitude, and altitude of the plane at the specified timestamp.

With this dataset I want to make queries like

> For a specified flight, what other flights came within X distance over this specified time range.

Does anyone know of a database or in memory framework that supports these types of temporal geospatial queries with the caveat that the timestamps do not necessarily align?